# Linux executes a command on a remote Windows server without SSH/Telnet

Tags: deployment, jenkins, continuous-integration, cross-platform, remote-access

I am building a Jenkins server. One of the deployment steps is to execute a command on the production server to download the UAT-tested artifacts to the required folders. Jenkins is running on CentOS Linux while the production server is running Windows 2008 R2.

However, my client does not want to install any software into the production server, therefore executing commands via SSH is not possible. The client had an unpleasant experience with using Telnet before. It is an insecure service which has already been disabled on the server.

Other than using SSH and Telnet, are there other ways to execute a command on a remote machine? I was thinking of creating a task that is triggered by a specific event, but how to raise the event on the server remotely seems not an easy job.

Comment: @Kate Gregory, Thanks for correcting the question text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of four different solutions:

1. Have a network share on the production machine that your Jenkins server can put a trigger file into. Have a scheduled task that checks for that file and triggers the download.
2. Have a scheduled task on the production machine poll the Jenkins server for new files. Powershell can be used to query the Jenkins REST api.
3. If the production machine has IIS, get Jenkins to trigger an asp.net script, do a form POST to a cgi script, or upload a trigger file. curl and wget on CentOS will help there.
4. As a last resort, add another windows machine into the mix. Install SSH onto it. Use SSH from Jenkins to the new machine, then powershell from the new machine to the production machine.

If you decide on step 4, I use Power Shell to run commands on a remote machine.

PS2.0 is installed on Windows 2008 R2 by default.

Here is an example of how I do it.

```
$username = 'user'
$password = 'password'
$appHost = 'hostname'
$dest = 'C:\Unpack\'
$archive = "C:\Releases\new release.7z"

$securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $password -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$securePass

"Create PowerShell Session"
$appSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $appHost -Credential $cred -Authentication CredSSP 

invoke-command -session $appSession -scriptblock { param($dest,$archive) & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe' x -bd -aoa """-oc:\$dest""" """c:\$dest\$archive"""} -args $dest,$archive
$remotelastexitcode = invoke-command -session $appSession -ScriptBlock { $lastexitcode }
if ( $remotelastexitcode -ne 0 )
{
  "Archive Extraction Failed. Is a file locked or open?"
  exit -1
}
```

Comment: How can this be run on a Linux machine?

Comment: Thanks Stuart, you are giving great options! I like option 3, and will give it a try.